# possible to determine action since 2 secs elapsed since last keypress

Tags: javascript

i have a textbox html element as shown:

```
<input type="text" id="emailaddress" value="Emailaddress"/>
```

What id like to accomplish is code that will only activate after the user has released the key 2 seconds after the keyup event was fired.

So, for example:

User  types in their respective emailaddress, and then we wait 2 seconds to determine that they are **indeed not typing anymore** and then I apply my validation code.

**I have an onkeydown for the tab key** and that works well but i am looking for the `onkeyup event and it must be fired extacly 2 seconds since the last keyup of this html element`

Comment: Waiting 2 seconds for validation might be overkill. In my experience users don't wait that much time after entering their data. If you really needed to, you can setup a time-based check that periodically checks when was the last 'keyup' and if its more than two seconds ago, trigger the validation.

Comment: @RishiB can you provide some code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a 'debounce'. Here is a simple example:

```js
var debounce;

document.getElementById('emailaddress').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  clearTimeout( debounce );
  
  debounce = setTimeout( function() {
    console.log('I waited 2 seconds before firing after last keyup');  
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="emailaddress" value=""/>
```

It only fires the code after the action has stopped being attempted for a set amount of time ( in this instance 2 seconds ). I agree with the commenters that 2 seconds is a long time, usually debounces for inputs are around 300ms ( in my experience ).